# Blade view to PDF in laravel (404 Not Found)

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I am trying to convert the Blade view to pdf

I have used the same way described [here](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-create-and-download-pdf-in-laravel-58example.html) but the result of the implementation is

> 404 | not found.

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

am using dompdf to generate pdf and i dont have problems.
you can follow the instructions bellow
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf